# How to properly align two connectors in Visio 2016?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I'm using Visio 2016. I want to align two connectors precisely. See below image. How can I do that? You can download my testing visio file at https://www.dropbox.com/s/6rtmnehydamx4wg/sed.vsdx?dl=1

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You can use I think it's shift + cursor key to make tiny changes. I don't have visio installed right about now so I can't check for you.

Comment: I have noticed that you have posted the same question in TechNet and I replied it to the thread. I will follow up to help you there.